# i want to retain my input field data even after search is done

Tags: javascript, java, spring

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/search")
public String personList(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee e,ModelMap map,@RequestParam("drop") String value) 
{
    /*System.out.println("In Controller " + e.getEmployeeName() +" "+ value);*/
    map.put("drop",value);
    map.put("employee",e);
    map.put("employeeList", employeeService.employeeList(e.getEmployeeName(),value)); 
    return "ViewPage";
}
```

Above is my controller code

```
<form:form  action="search.html" modelAttribute="employee" method="POST">

<select id="ViewByName" class ="dropdown" name= "drop">
 <!-- <option value="r">Select....</option>  -->
  <option value="s">Starts With</option>
  <option value="c">Consist Of</option>
  <option value="e">Ends With</option>
</select>

            <div id="search-inner">
                <td>
                <form:input path="employeeName" type="text" name="search" maxlength="30" id="searchfield" title="searchfield" value="type the name of employee to search..." class = "search" 
                onfocus="if (this.value=='type the name of employee to search...') this.value=''" 
                 onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value ='type the name of employee to search...'"/>

              <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Name Search"   title="Search" />

                </td>
            </div>
</form:form>
```

Above is my JSP page code.
My problem is when i select some option from dropdown and enter text entry search based on dropdown value after searching I input field goes to default text but i want to retain it in search result page.

Comment: All the values are not coming to page or partially?

Comment: every thing works fine but input textbox will reseted to default after entering search page i.e,type the name of employee to search... in search page

Comment: Your default setting of "value" makes the problem.

Comment: that's right but where should I fix that bug in my code

Comment: please check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Post-edit for record

The solution was simply turning your value="" to placeholder="" on the search input field.

Value was overriding the information coming from the binding.

Comment: Well, is the ViewPage the same JSP you use for search? Or does it include the search fragment?

Comment: There's no form opening tag in the snippet you posted. Did you set the modelAttribute="employee" attr on form opening tag?
With that info, it's not needed to set the employeeName in the model, since the input will get its value from the employee model.

Comment: yes I set my modelAttribute = "employee" in my jsp page

Answer (score 1):

You can do with request parameter like as :

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/search")
public String personList(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee e,ModelMap     map,@RequestParam("drop") String value,HttpServetRequest request) 
{
    request.setparameter("searchdata",drop);
    /*System.out.println("In Controller " + e.getEmployeeName() +" "+ value);*/
    map.put("drop",value);
    map.put("employee",e);
       map.put("employeeList",employeeService.employeeList(e.getEmployeeName(),value)); 
    return "ViewPage";
}
```

On jsp page you can get value like as

```
<%= request.getParameter("searchdata") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change code as below: (jsp)

```
 <form:input path="employeeName" type="text" name="search" maxlength="30" id="searchfield" title="searchfield" class = "search"  value="${not empty employee.employeeName? employee.employeeName : 'type the name of employee to search'}" />
```

and add jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchfield").focus(function(){
    if (this.value == "type the name of employee to search")
    {
        this.value = "";
        $(this).css('color','#000000');
     }
    });

    $("#searchfield").blur(function(){

            if (this.value == "")
            {
                this.value = "type the name of employee to search";
                $(this).css('color','#a9a9a9');
            }
        });});
```

Answer (score 0):

IN jsp instead of value="type the name of employee to search..." 
placeholder="type the name of employee to search..." should be used then it works fine and retains the input field data even after search is done.
thanks for all your suggestions....

Answer (score 0):

```
<form:input path="employeeName" type="text" name="search" maxlength="30" id="searchfield" title="searchfield" placeholder="type the name of employee to search..." class = "search" 
            onfocus="if (this.value=='type the name of employee to search...') this.value=''" 
             onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value ='type the name of employee to search...'"/>
```